# Why is this CSS animation crashing chrome and how can I fix it?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-animations

Have a look at this code:
CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes crashChrome {
        0%{ -webkit-transform: translateX(0rem);}   
}




.anim:before{
    content: "";    
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    border-radius: 3rem;      
    position: absolute;
    left:5rem;  
    top: 5rem;
        background-color: #06839f;  

        -webkit-animation: crashChrome;  
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="anim"></div>
```

The code can be found here: http://codepen.io/OpherV/pen/xsemw/

If you open this in chrome, you get:
[image]

http://codepen.io/OpherV/pen/xsemw/

I think this has something to do with pseudo elements and transformations.
How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

here you are using rem instead of px or em. I tried it using px and it worked on my google chrome browser.

take a look

```
<div class="anim"></div>
<style>
@-webkit-keyframes crashChrome {
    0%{ -webkit-transform: translateX(5px);}   
}
.anim:before{
content: "";    
width: 5px;
height: 5px;
border-radius: 1px;      
position: absolute;
left:50px;  
top: 50px;
    background-color: #06839f;  

    -webkit-animation: crashChrome;  
}
</style>
```

Try it